# How to parse this type of datetime data

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, data-science

I am trying to convert these string objects to python datetime objects but the letter T,Z are creating a problem.

```py
datetime.strptime(i,'%Y-%m-%d').date() for i in df['dateUpdated']

0    2014-02-01T04:41:06Z
1    2013-12-11T05:28:28Z
2    2015-11-19T22:20:29Z
3    2014-02-01T05:22:01Z
4    2016-05-19T14:31:26Z

ValueError: unconverted data remains: T04:41:06Z
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are working with Pandas, use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'dateUpdated': ['2014-02-01T04:41:06Z', '2013-12-11T05:28:28Z']})
df['dateUpdated'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dateUpdated'])
```

Results:

```
0   2014-02-01 04:41:06+00:00
1   2013-12-11 05:28:28+00:00
Name: dateUpdated, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

If you then want to access only the date part of your new column, you can use:

```
df['dateUpdated'].dt.date
```